# Docker save: No such image

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

When i run  `docker save nifi > nifi_backup.tar` i get

```
Error response from daemon: No such image: nifi
```

When i run `docker ps -a` i got

```
$docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                      PORTS                                       NAMES
a8796cbf6cb1   apache/nifi:1.9.2   "../scripts/start.sh"    11 months ago   Exited (0) 33 minutes ago                                               nifi
f4ecf6ca0d16   apache/nifi         "../scripts/start.sh"    12 months ago   Exited (0) 12 months ago                                                nervous_poincare
9a68c235bb3a   apache/nifi         "../scripts/start.sh"    12 months ago   Exited (0) 12 months ago                                                jolly_mendel
d608287fe560   superset_superset   "/entrypoint.sh"         2 years ago     Up 27 hours (healthy)       0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp, :::8088->8088/tcp   superset_superset_1
fcea620b1983   postgres:10         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 years ago     Up 27 hours                 0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp, :::5433->5432/tcp   superset_postgres_1
380782e0a024   redis:3.2           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 years ago     Up 27 hours                 0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp   superset_redis_1
```

Also, i cant start nifi image

if i run `docker start nifi`

it try to start about a minute, but then stop silently.

And there is no logs in result.

`docker events` says `exit code = 0`:

[image]

Maybe it has some relation for unavailable saving, so i inform about it too.

How to fix `No such image` in such a case?

Comment: Do you want to save an image or the state of the container? If it's the container: What is it that you want to backup and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command `docker images` to see if there is an image named nifi. If not first build that image and than execute the command:

```
docker save nifi > nifi_backup.tar
```

It should not show the error `No such image: nifi` if the command `docker images` has an image named nifi.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/), `docker save` command expects an image name, not a container. You're probably looking for `docker export` ([export docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/)) command to achieve what you want.

The error about starting your container could be container-specific. As it exited already a year ago, maybe data is lost and the container cannot be started again. Using command `docker events&`, you can start the docker event listener in the background. This way you can obtain the hex value of this very start attempt and use it to search specific logs: `docker logs <startId hex>`. Maybe it can tell you more details about why the container did not properly start.

Comment: i try ` docker save -o nifi_12_11_2021.tar nifi`,  and `docker save nifi > nifi_backup.tar` and it say `Error response from daemon: No such image: nifi`. Dont `nifi` is a name of container?

Comment: `logs` are empty/ Docker events say `exit code = 0`

Comment: Update my question with screenshoot of docker events

Comment: No, as per your screenshot the name of the image is `apache/nifi:1.9.2` so a valid command would be `docker save apache/nifi:1.9.2 > nifi_image.tar` but that is not what you want I guess. If you want to save the state of the container, use `docker export nifi > nifi_container.tar` as I stated earlier.

Comment: Concerning the log output, I would say the container just died, nothing special there. Could it be that the container is missing any configuration? [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/) under heading "Running a container" they pass some arguments. Could it be that they are missing and because of that the container does not come up properly? Are you able to run a new container based on this documentation? e.g. `docker run -dit --name -p8443:8443 nifi_test apache/nifi:1.9.2`. Or maybe something is already running under the configured port of the old container?